# Java Swing GUI Adding a Frame Container to another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jframe

I´ve got a class which extends JFrame. An Object of this class should contain another object from another class which also extends from JFrame. If I want do add the object from the secound class to the object from the fist class I get the error adding a window to a container.
How can I solve this problem? Or is it a huge mistake to add one JFrame to annother. And how could I solve this otherwise. I have one GridLayout which contains lots of Buttons(this is my secound class) and under these grid I want to have other buttons, but not in the grid. So I created the first class with a Flowlayout, adding the Grid und adding the other buttons

Comment: You can't add a `JFrame` to another. Maybe add the `contentPane` of the frame to the other one? But a better way would be by nesting layouts. The way I understand your requirement would suggest that the main panel has a [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), add the panel with the `GridLayout` to it's `CENTER` and add the panel with the `FlowLayout` to the `SOUTH`. Or, if you want just one of panels visible on the whole frame, use [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: And welcome to the wonderful world of why you should extend from top level containers

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem :) Do you also have an idea how I can reload the grid if for example a button was pressed?

Comment: @Alex What exactly do you mean by 'reload'? If you want to dynamically change the contents of the panel with `GridLayout`, you have to call `panel.revalidate()` and `panel.repaint()` afterwards.

Comment: I now have the Frame wich has a border layout. To an object of this class I add an object of a JPanel which contains the grid. And I add annother object of a onother JPanel which contains the buttons. If I now press one of the buttons I want to call a methode and create the grid new and change the grid placed in the Frame

Comment: @Alex If each button has one grid 'assigned' to it, a `CardLayout` or even a `TabbedPane` without any buttons would do fine. If that's not what you mean, call `mainPanel.remove(panel_width_gridlayout)`, create a brand new grid and add it to the main panel (don't forget to call `revalidate` and `repaint`).

Comment: You need to get a conceptual understanding of Java Swing.  Oracle has this tutorial, [Trail: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).  Take your time, and go through the tutorial.  Don't skip any pages.  Study each page carefully.  Take months or even years to go through and understand the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. It works if the button is in the same class as the mainPanel. But how can I call the methode in which the grid gets resetted if my button is in annother class?